# Connect to an Empty Activity app to a physical device

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, usb

Recently, I tried to build an empty activity app using Android Studio for some poc purposes. I connected the app to a physical device through USB. When running the app, it is working on the device just fine except that it does not save the app to the device.
Whereas when I created the app using basic activity and run in the device, it saves the app on my device's screen and installed it into the memory.
Does anybody know the reason and solution for this?

FYR, I am using Huawei VOG-L29 as the device for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the app in the device somehow.  The template you use to create the initial project doesn't matter-  its not part of the final build.  Android Studio doesn't even remember it once it's done generating the initial files.  When you upload an app to the device, it will be saved to internal storage and should appear in settings.

Comment: Oh, you are right, it is being saved to the internal storage. But then why it does not show up on the mobile screen? I cannot find a way to open the app as well. Unlike the empty activity, when I install the basic activity template, it is registered as an app on the mobile and can be opened with a tap on the screen.

Comment: Do you have an activity set as the launcher activity?  If not, then it won't appear in the list of apps.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It turns out that I got the intent-filters mixed up together, when I separated the launcher activity and the rest of the categories, it works fine now.